# Routes in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to build a portfolio in react. When I render the nav bar I can click on the links and the url says I am going to where I need to go, but I keep getting a white page/
// The app.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./components/About";
import SinglePost from "./components/SinglePost";
import Post from "./components/Post";
import Project from "./components/Project";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar"

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
    <NavBar/>
      <Routes>
        <Route component={Home} path ="/" exact />
        <Route component={About} path ="/about"/>
        <Route component={SinglePost} path= "/post/:slug"/>
        <Route component={Post} path = "/post"/>
        <Route component={Project} path = "/project"/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}


export default App;
```

//the About.js file

```
import React from "react"

export default function About(){
    return <h1>About Page!</h1>
}
```

Comment: You need to create a runnable example of your code in https://codesandbox.io and then describe exactly what you did and what you need, if you need help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to `HashRouter` as it's more stable across browsers, especially old ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to wrap your Routes in Swicth

```
import { Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
     <BrowserRouter>
        <NavBar/>
        <Switch>
          
            <Route component={Home} path ="/" exact />
            <Route component={About} path ="/about"/>
            <Route component={SinglePost} path= "/post/:slug"/>
            <Route component={Post} path = "/post"/>
            <Route component={Project} path = "/project"/>
        
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```